# Postman -Express API on Localhost GET and POST requests giving 404 error

Tags: express, rest, postman, http-status-code-404

I want to test out **POST** requests using **POSTMAN** but even for **GET** request as well as **POST**, I get **404**.
I am using it on *localhost* port *4000* route *articles* (tried *http://localhost:4000/articles* as well as *http://127.0.0.1:4000/articles *on POSTMAN) but they both return 404.

```
//CREATE - POST (App.js code) 

app.post("/articles",function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body.title);
    console.log(req.body.content);
});
```

Otherwise if I enter the localhost address in the browser, I do GET the response.

> I have entered a **KEY** and **VALUE** for title and content in the Body > x-www-form-urlencoded in POSTMAN to see it in the console log to check for POST request, but it looks like it does not connect to the link.

(I read about proxy disabling in another answer, which I have disabled now in Settings (the *USE SYSTEM PROXY* setting) but still no change, do I need to leave the proxy off?).

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Tried sending the POST and GET request but it gives me a 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://localhost:4000/articles
```

I had accidentally hit 'Enter' at the end of the URL on postman. Had to go down and delete the 'new line' and it worked.

Comment: It was mostly done by mistake.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).